# Multisim - how to view Op-Amp Voltage Saturation

Tags: operational-amplifier

[multisim-print](http://prntscr.com/dg5ceq)

Hello! I am learning electronics in university and need to get the Voltage Saturation for this Amp-Op circuit (it might be easy but I don't know how to do it...), the print above also has the DC Sweep graph.

If you need more info I'll give it, sorry if the question is not very good, it's my first electronics question!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add the definition of saturation voltage as provide by your course materials? I suspect that may lead you to a way to characterize it.

Comment: @uint128_t Sadly I do not know how to calculate it... The materials available are very low... From the practical classes we've used a given value as saturation voltage so I don't know how I should find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want to duplicate this spec?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand OP-AMPs quite well... Should I power with with Vcc + and Vcc -? Or ground and Vcc +? I think it's an Inversor circuit using ideal OP-AMP.